# MySql Store Date like YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: mysql

i have a database structure like this

```
name          |   birthdate
---------------------------------
varcahr(255)  |    date
```

i am inserting date in (yyyy/mm/dd) like this using jquery date pickeer '1985/08/22'

but Mysql store it like '1985-08-22'

there is any way that i can store date like '1985/08/22' i want to store slash not '-'.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Format data when you display it, not when you store it.

Comment: At edit time it's not looking good so i want if it is possible...

Comment: The point is that you should save dates using native YYYY-MM-DD (and as DATE datatype) and change it to YYYY/MM/DD or whatever you want *when you pull the data*, not when you save it.

Answer (score 3):

You should store the data in the native date format, for efficiency in calculation, etc.  You can control the format of the dates going into the tables and selecting from them in your queriers.  For example, you can insert data using the str_to_date function:

```
INSERT into table1(birthdate) 
VALUES STR_TO_DATE('2009/01/01','%m/%d/%y')
```

For selecting your date, you can use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m/%d/%y') 
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not **store** the date as a specific string. It only **represents** dates like that. See [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to display a speccific date representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (name, birthdate) VALUES(
            'mit', STR_TO_DATE('2009/03/08', '%Y/%m/%d'));
```

Comment: there is error like #1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '2009/03/08' for function str_to_date

Comment: ooops forgot to change the format to STR_TO_DATE('2009/03/08', '%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: you can customize the specifier by yourself on this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: it still inserting date like '2009-03-08' ..:(

Comment: how do you look the date? impossible if direct select on database. check how to show it. it must be like SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM table

Comment: change it to SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%Y/%m/%d') 
FROM table